# TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable after upgrade to django 1.5.1

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py

After upgrading from django 1.2.7 to 1.5.1
when trying to run celery by using

```
python manage.py celeryd -v 2 -l INFO --settings=settings
```

i got an error saying that

```
django.core.management.execute_manager
```

is deprecated in django 1.4

my manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import execute_manager
try:
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_from_command_line(settings)
```

I looked at django 1.4 release notes

[django-core-management-execute-manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-core-management-execute-manager)

as it says there i replaced the execute_manager with a execute_from_command_line

and now i started getting this error message when i restart the server

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\my\manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 452, in     execute_from_command_line
    utility = ManagementUtility(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.prog_name = os.path.basename(self.argv[0])
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a wrong argument to the `execute_from_command_line` method. You should do something like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<package>.<subpackage>.settings") #path to the settings py file
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<package>.<subpackage>.settings") #path to the settings py file
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line() # by default sys.argv argument is taken
```

Indeed, the argument of `execute_from_command_line` is, as its name suggests, a parsed command line where the 1st element is the executable name, and the others are arguments